# Ctrl Alt [Left, Right, Up, Down] doesn't captured by any application in Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I recognize VSCode doesn't capture ✲ Ctrl ⎇ Alt ↑ ↓ ← → Arrow in Windows 10, and finally found that any application doesn't capture too.

Comment: maybe you are using RDP (remote desktop)? This is issue with native client which catch this shortcuts and don't pass them to remote client.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happends by Intel Graphic Command Center. Open Intel Graphic Command Center and toggle, disable or assign new hotkey and disable these settings that below.

> Check [YEmreAk.com](https://lib.yemreak.com/uygulamalar/vs-code/hata-cozumleri#ctrl-alt-arrow-kisayolunun-calismamasi) if you can understand Turkish.

[image]